# How to run celery as daemon with normal celery command

Tags: python, django, celery, celery-task, celeryd

I have a django app for which i am using celery tasks to perform some csv processing in background, and so i installed `rabbitmq-server` like `sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server`, by this command the rabbitmq-server was installed and running successfully.

And i have some celery tasks code in `tasks.py` module inside an app and running the celery like below

```
celery -A app.tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

which was working fine and executing the csv files in background successfully, but now i just want to daemonize the above command, and i searched about any option to daemonize it but i din't found any arguments to pass like `-D` to daemonize the above command. So is there anyway that i can daemonize the above command and make celery run ?

Comment: I use supervisorctl to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `--detach` option. [1]

But is recommended that you use something like systemd.
The celery docs has a whole page on this topic. [2]

[1] http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.base.html#daemon-options

[2] http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html

Answer (score 0):

**supervisorctl** will be a better bet on this.

Installation: `sudo apt-get install supervisor`

The main configuration file of supervisor is here: `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`

Run `$vim /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` to inspect. Looking into the file, at the bottom, youu'll notice:

```
[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

This basically means that config files of your projects can be stored here `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/` and they will be automatically included.

Run: `sudo vim /etc/supervisor/conf.d/myapp.conf`. Your configuration may look like:

```
[program:myapp]
command={{ your celery commands without curly braces }}
directory=/directory/to/myapp
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/myapp.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/myapp.out.log
```

To Restart service: `$sudo service supervisor restart`

To Re-read after making updates to any *.conf file: `$sudo supervisorctl reread`

To record updates: `$sudo supervisorctl update`

To check status of specific *.conf: `sudo supervisorctl status myapp`

Check your log files for more status data.